# read in image from SharePoint 2007 custom list & display @ Silverlight 2.0 control,

Tags: c#, asmx, silverlight-2.0

How may I read in images & display them on my Silverlight 2.0 control when my output is the following? (i'm currently using lists.asmx)

> 20;#http://moss:48420/Image Picker Picture
>   List/1e166fc4-a07a-4680-a52a-c04f75394cc9.jpg;#http://moss:48420/Image%20Picker%20Picture%20List/_t/1e166fc4-a07a-4680-a52a-c04f75394cc9_jpg.jpg

My Silverlight application is similar to: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-5-using-the-listbox-and-databinding-to-display-list-data.aspx

Snippet:

```
private void ProcessResponse2()
        {
            XDocument results = XDocument.Parse(_responseString);

            _StaffNews = (from item in results.Descendants(XName.Get("row", "#RowsetSchema"))

                          //where !item.Element("NewsThumbnail").Attribute("src").Value.EndsWith(".gif")
                          select new StaffNews()
                          {
                              Title = item.Attribute("ows_Title").Value,
                              NewsBody = item.Attribute("ows_NewsBody").Value,
                              Thumbnail = FormatImageUrl2(item.Attribute("ows_NewsThumbnail").Value),
                              DatePublished = item.Attribute("ows_Date_Published").Value,
                              PublishedBy = item.Attribute("ows_PublishedBy").Value,
                          }).ToList();

            this.NewsList.DataContext = _StaffNews;              
        }

private string FormatImageUrl2(string value)
        {
            return value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(','));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that i have to edit the lines within method 'FormatImageUrl2':

return value.Substring(value.LastIndexOf(";#") + 2);